# Archive for custom post type tags

Tags: wordpress

I've created a custom post type and have both a post and category archive for it. But when I click on the post tags the tag archive says "No results found". How do I create a archive for the tags?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time no results issues is related to google OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. You can read a bit about it [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-results-4?replies=3).

Can you please post a link to your site? i will try to see it this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by copying the archive.php and renamed it to tag.php in the theme folder.